# How to use sqlInterpolate to add a new row of data to SQL from R Shiny?

Tags: sql, r, shiny, interpolation

I have an existing table (Data_table) in SQL and want to use R Shiny to let users add a new row to the 2 column table.

I have created a text field (Lookupname) for the value in the first column and drop down selection (Lookupdropdown) for the value in the second column, then a button to action these (Lookupbutton)

I have done two attempts are observe events...

```
  observeEvent(
    input$Lookupbutton,{
      lookup1 <- paste0(input$Lookupname)
      lookup2 <- paste0(input$Lookupdropdown)
      queryString <- dbExecute(db, sqlInterpolate(db,
                                                   "INSERT INTO `Data_table` (`Name`, `Category`) 
                                                   VALUES ('?lookuptext1', '?lookuptext2') "
                                                   , lookuptext1=dbQuoteIdentifier(db, lookup1)
                                                   , lookuptext2=dbQuoteIdentifier(db, lookup2)))})
```

This one just prints "?lookuptext1" and "?lookuptext2" in the cells

I then tried...

```
  observeEvent(
    input$Lookupbutton,{
      lookup1 <- paste0(input$Lookupname)
      lookup2 <- paste0(input$Lookupdropdown)
      queryString <- dbExecute(db, sqlInterpolate(db,
                                                   "INSERT INTO `Data_table` (`Name`, `Category`) 
                                                   VALUES (?lookuptext1, ?lookuptext2) "
                                                   , lookuptext1=dbQuoteIdentifier(db, lookup1)
                                                   , lookuptext2=dbQuoteIdentifier(db, lookup2)))})
```

But get an error message about the value I have written as ?lookuptext1 not being in 'field list'. What does this mean? It is not a column title, as they are Name and Category.

Thanks

Comment: There is no need to do that, just use `dbWriteTable` directly, something like this: `newdata <- data.frame(...); dbWriteTable(db, "Data_table", newdata, create=FALSE, append=TRUE)`.

Comment: FYI, `paste0(input$Lookupname)` is doing nothing, drop `paste0`.

Comment: For future reference, please make sure that your code is reproducible (e.g. a simple shiny app)